# Upgrade Magento 2.4.5 Errors : Call method 'Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface::save' that does not exist on version '2.4.5'

Tags: magento2.4.5

After upgrading magento I found this critical error.
Please guide me to solve this error.

Compatibility tool error :
Call method 'Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface::save' that does not exist on version '2.4.5'

I have my custom module file like,
I have extended class and trying to save custom attribute value.

```
namespace Softweb\CustomCheckout\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;

/**
 * Class SaveSapOrderId
 */
class SaveSapInfo extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order implements HttpPostActionInterface
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $order = $this->_initOrder();
        if ($order) {
            try {
                $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('sap_order_id');
                $order->setData('sap_order_id', $data);
                $order->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Your SAP information saved successfully'));
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('We can\'t save SAP Order ID.'));
                $this->logger->critical($e);
            }
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath(
                'sales/order/view',
                [
                    'order_id' => $order->getEntityId()
                ]
            );
        }
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('sales/*/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please Elaborate more, how you are using the Interface..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to save order

```
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
class SaveSapInfo extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order 
implements HttpPostActionInterface
 {   
 private $orderManagement;

  public function __construct(
     OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement
   ){
     $this->orderManagement = $orderManagement;
    }
public function execute()
{
    $order = $this->_initOrder();
    if ($order) {
        try {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('sap_order_id');
            $order->setData('sap_order_id', $data);
            $this->orderManagement->save($order->getEntityId());
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Your SAP information saved successfully'));
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('We can\'t save SAP Order ID.'));
            $this->logger->critical($e);
        }
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath(
            'sales/order/view',
            [
                'order_id' => $order->getEntityId()
            ]
        );
    }
    return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('sales/*/');
   }
}
```